# saving and updating on serialized column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Apologies in advance for the ugly code (in addition to it not working).

I have a Rails app that has many users who play different quiz games, which were created by various users. There is no rails-style association between user and quizes except that each quiz has been made by a particular user.  There's actually not even a 'quiz' model in the application (quizes are made of question and answer models).

For obvious reasons, users are only allowed to try each quiz once; therefore, I have to record which users' quizers a particular user has tried. Therefore, I created a 'quiz' attribute on the user model, and serialized it, so that I would hopefully have a database column like this `['2','4','10']` if I had played the quizes that were made by users with ids 2,4 and 10.

In the user model, after creating :quiz as a 'string',  I did this to turn the string into an array in the db

```
  attr_accessible :quiz
  serialize :quiz
```

However, I'm having a lot of trouble writing code that does all of the following

a) checks if that column's not empty (maybe the player hasn't played a quiz yet): I did `player.quiz?` to test that.

b) checking whether the array includes a particular user.id (i.e. if the player has already played that quiz)  I do  `player.quiz.include?(user.id.to_s)` to test that

c) creating the first entry if a user hasn't played any quizzes yet. I did `quiz = user.id.to_s`

d) adding to the array of game's once a user's played a second user's game (i.e. player's quiz column is ['2'] and now they play quiz by user.id 4.

With various combinations of the code below, I keep erasing/resetting the quiz column when I try to update, or I'm creating strings like '68' when I want ['6','8'] instead.

I'd be grateful if you could give me some tips to fix this up.

**code not working**

```
       if player && player.quiz? && player.quiz.include?(user.id.to_s) #checks if signed in (if player), if the player.quiz column isn't empty, and if it includes a user id

          alreadyplayedthisquiz = true
       else
           if player.quiz?            #it might be that no quizzes are registered on db

            quiz = player.quiz     #this is a string
            quiz.push(user.id.to_s)  #can't push onto a string
            quiz += user.id.to_s    #this is wrong, because if I've played quiz 6 and 8, it'll be '68' in the db
           else 
            quiz = user.id.to_s     #if no quiz on player's db, create first one

           end

          alreadyplayedthisquiz = false
      end

      player.update_attributes({quiz: quiz})
```

Comment: Any particular reason that you're storing a CSVd array in a single column instead of use a traditional association table?

Comment: @muistooshort this was the first and only idea that occurred to me. If you have time, can you suggest how I might set up the association table, keeping in mind that there's no quiz.rb model.

Comment: You'd start by defining a quiz model (better now than later). Then a you'd have a `(person_id,quiz_id)` table with a unique index on on `(person_id,quiz_id)` to keep track of which person has done which quiz.

Comment: thanks, do I have to define associations in the models to make it work? Based on what you said, I'd think no. Does it matter what the table's called (i.e. will I benefit from rails 'conventions' by giving it a certain name). I'm googling 'rails association table' and coming up with a lot of Railscasts on polymorphic association. I'm guessing the two are different?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), the [associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in particular.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a has_many :through would work best, but I ran into a bit of a problem. Before I try to rewrite everything (and if you have any time) would you offer your advice http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424875/how-to-make-this-work-as-a-has-many-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would store the values in the database as `"2","4","6"` rather than as `["2","4","6"]`.  The `[` and `]` are not necessary.

I would use the `String#split` to convert the string in the database to an array that can be used in the code.  I would use `Array#join` to convert the array used in the code back into a string for storage in the database.

```
quiz = player.quiz? ? player.quiz.split(",") : []
alreadyplayedthisquiz = quiz.include? user.id.to_s
if (!alreadyplayedthisquiz)
  quiz.push user.id.to_s
  player.update_attributes({:quiz => quiz.join(",")})
end
```

Comment: the serialize :quiz method in the user model puts multiple strings into the array. so does your solution mean that I don't need it I guess?

Comment: Ok, I tried it with and without serialize :quiz and it works both ways. Thanks a lot.