# how to make this work as a has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if you can give me some advice on how to use a has_many :through association in this situation before I spend a whole lot of time rewriting my code to possibly no avail.

I have a user model, and each user can play many quizzes (and therefore generate many quiz scores).  Right now, the player starts a game by clicking on a user's name, which triggers a query for all the quiz questions that that user (a user has_many :questions) has made

```
  def startGame 

     user = User.find_by_name(params[:user])
     questions = user.questions

  end
```

For obvious reasons, a player can't play the same quiz twice. Although I figured out a way to prevent that, I didn't do it an efficient way. Someone suggested I try an association table. I started that association table as a `has_many :through` with this plan

User.rb  (this user is the user-as-player, not the user-as-quiz maker)

```
has_many :scores
has_many :quizzes, :through => :scores
```

Quiz.rb

```
   has_many :scores
   has_many :users    :through => :scores
```

Score

```
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :quiz
```

The problem is that, currently, there is no quiz model or quiz anything. Quizzes are in fact just made up of questions (Question.rb) and answers (Answer.rb).  For example, each user `has_many :questions` and each question `has_many :answers` like this

User.rb

```
has_many :questions
```

Question.rb

```
has_many :answers
```

So what can I make the Quiz model (or whatever I would call it) out of?

One idea that occured to me was to make a Quiz.rb model and do

```
has_many :questions
```

which would mean Question.rb belongs to both User.rb and Quiz.rb.

Can I then do the `has_many :through` as described above with User, Quiz and Score? If so, Score will have both a user_id (for the player) and a quiz_id (for the quiz), but since the purpose of this whole association is to prevent users playing the same quiz twice, I'm wondering how I could make it work with the following code.

```
  def startGame

   user = User.find_by_name(params[:user])  #this user is the quiz creator
   questions = user.questions
     .....
    #I want to check right here if they've already played the quiz. how to do it with the has_many :through of Quiz, Score, User (as player)

  end
```

With the user.rb (player), score.rb, quiz.rb set up, how would I check if they've played this particular quiz in this situation.

Also, if I make the quiz model and do has_many :questions, would I would have to use polymorphism since user.rb also has_many :questions?

Update: I want to check whether they've already played in the `def startGame` method and not let them continue the game if they have. i.e. I don't want to wait until it's time to save the score to see if a score for that quiz has already been saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks very good already.  If you want to prevent any player from playing a quiz more than once, you can make any combination of a user and a quiz unique.  You can add this to your scores migration:

```
add_index :scores, [:user_id, :quiz_id], unique: true
```

And add this to your Scores model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: quiz_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but does that mean you'd do everything the same. So you would do Quiz.rb has_many :questions? Does it matter that User.rb already has_many :questions? do I have to use polymorphism? Is it ok "as-is" that Quiz and User both has_many :questions?

Comment: Your answer seems to assume that I do the uniqueness check after they play again (and presumably not let them save if they've already played once). However, I want to check in the startGame method and stop them from playing again.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil: You could check `quizzes` to see if the quiz is there and complain if you find it.

Comment: @muistooshort I know, but that's the problem I was having with the association, which I didn't make clear in the question. If you look at the startGame method, and how it pulls the questions for the quiz, I don't know how to make that connect to the Quiz.rb model so that I can do the checking you suggest. If the associations are User (as player) has_many :scores, Quiz has_many :scores, Scores belongs_to :user and :quiz, then how, keepign in mind startGame code, do I do that check. I can't also do User (as quiz creator) has_one :quiz, can I? because that'd make a big circle.

Comment: You can check to see if a user has played a quiz by doing `user.quizzes.include?(quiz)` or `user.quizzes.find(quiz.id)`.  There are other ways, but those should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: @jimStewart sorry it took so long, trying to wrap my thick head around things. I didn't know how to associate quiz.rb with the various questions and answers that formed the 'quiz' before the quiz model was created.